# Why doesn't gridheight have any effect on my GridBagLayout panel? How do you combine it with weighty?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm new to GridBagLayout.

While I really like the concept behind it, it doesn't seem to be so intuitive in practice.

Take the following code for example:

```
public class TestGridBack {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //initialise constraints
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.weightx = 1.0;
    constraints.weighty = 1.0;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    //set constraints for new label
    constraints.gridy = 0; //row 1
    constraints.gridx = 0; //column 1
    constraints.gridwidth = 1; //horizontal width 1
    constraints.gridheight = 1; //vertical length 1
    //add label
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(label, constraints);

    //set constraints for new button
    constraints.gridy = 1; //row 2
    constraints.gridx = 0; //column 1
    constraints.gridwidth = 1; //horizontal width 1
    constraints.gridheight = 5; //vertical length 5
    //add button
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"), constraints);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

In the example above, you would expect something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2NRH.png

But instead you end up with this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jn8.png

Both the label and the button are using up the same amount of space.

Now I know that a solution to this would be to change the 'weighty' of the label and of the button so that the latter is 5 times longer than the previous, but why is this necessary? Isn't the whole idea behind 'gridheight' to allow this?

When I change the 'weighty' values, changing the 'gridheight' values still has no effect on my panel.

When is 'gridheight' useful? How are we supposed to combine the 'gridheight' and 'weighty'?

Comment: I would suggest putting your Label inside a Panel before putting it in the main Panel. I find that putting things in JPanels usually ends up solving sizing issues.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the code accordingly.